# Should we curb down on "most useful" questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we please have more strictness on SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/can-we-please-have-more-strictness-on-su)

I know they're useful, but it's getting rather annoying. SU is overrun by all sorts of **most useful** questions. I wouldn't mind this that much, but nobody bothers to make them **CW** before posting. They are there only for gaining reputation; I'm not sure they even care about the answers.

At the moment there are well over 15 questions of this kind.

Comment: What do you think is the most useful way to tackle this problem?

Comment: I have no idea. Lower tolerance from the moderators, perhaps?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/can-we-please-have-more-strictness-on-su

Comment: @John Smithers thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Well over 15 in just short of 10K questions - I would not call this overrun. And in an evaluation situation I would love to have a source where I can get such lists and reward the people helping me out with reputation.

I agree with a lower tolerance from the mods - unless the OP points to his use case for the answer:

- I want to learn more about Windows - what are the most useful shortcuts? -> CW
- In my project I need a ... to ..., what are the most useful ones -> not CW, even though there is not one correct answer. But there is one that is most useful for the OP.

Comment: Just having **most useful** in it does not qualify it for CW, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

They are only rep gainers if people upvote, if people upvote it's useful for them, if it's useful they deserve (some) rep.

Else we just need a flag option to mark it for CW (though I expect a lot of whines then from people who lost rep because of this)

Comment: This type of question is low hanging fruit. People vote them because they might find them interesting later on and because they're easy to understand and have an opinion on. I've done this as well, although I could have simply marked them as favorite.